# x and y coordinates are not correct when trying to read a matrix (python)

Tags: python, matrix, coordinates

I am trying to read a matrix (from another file) and check if the numbers are 1,2,3,4 or 5. But when i check I check the coordinates (code below) the x and y is not correct.

```
with open('/directory/to/file', 'r') as f:
    for index,row in enumerate([line.split() for line in f]):
        for i,num in enumerate(row):
            if num == '1':
                print(index,i,'=1')
            elif num == '2':
                print(index,i,'=2')
            elif num == '3':
                print(index,i,'=3')
            elif num == '4':
                print(index,i,'=4')
            elif num == '5':
                print(index,i,'=5')
```

this is my matrix:

```
[[0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,2,0,0,0],
 [0,3,0,0,0],
 [0,0,4,0,0],
 [0,0,5,0,0]]
```

but this is my result:

```
1 2 =1
2 2 =2
3 2 =3
4 3 =4
5 3 =5
```

I know it has to do something with this part:

```
with open('/directory/to/file', 'r') as f:
    for index,row in enumerate([line.split() for line in f]):
        for i,num in enumerate(row):
```

but I don't know how to fix it.
Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: It would help if you posted an example of the data, your output, and the expected output. But is the problem that everything is off by 1?

Comment: I will edit my question, wait a minute

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't your result. Did you mean that is what you want?

Comment: your input contains extra characters like '[' ']' and ',' (array brackets and comma). Your code is assuming that input is space separated numbers. so either you code should parse input correctly, or you can change your input to simple space separated numbers in each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `enumerate` starts enumerating with 0. You want it to start with one. It has an optional second parameter that allows you to do this:

```
class enumerate(object)
 |  enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
 |  
 |  Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
 |  iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
 |  start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
 |  enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
```

So your problem is simply solved by passing a `start` argument, in your case, 1:

```
with open('/directory/to/file', 'r') as f:
    for i,row in enumerate([line.split() for line in f], 1):
        for j,num in enumerate(row, 1):
            if num in (1,2,3,4,5):
                print(i,j,'=',num)
```

I also took the liberty of using i and j for the indices, it seems more natural. I also made the body of your inner loop more concise.